# Modifying the /sys/devices/system/memory/ directory of Sysfs in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel-module, numa

I am working on my course homework for modifying the memory directory of Sysfs in Linux Kernel. I am seeking help from people here after taking permission from my prof. Here's what I exactly want to do.

Background: If I have a 4 GB RAM I can have 4 X 1 GB DIMMS or 2X 2GB DIMMS on my motherboard. NUMA is supported in Linux by dividing this 4GB physical memory into many chunks with specific starting and ending physical address for each chunk. The 'devices' directory in Sysfs contains the global device hierarchy. This contains every physical device that has been discovered by the bus types registered with the kernel. Hence the details regarding the memory chunks are stored in the path '/sys/devices/system/memory/' of Linux Kernel. In this directory, we have a file called 'block_size_bytes' which decides how many parts my RAM can be split into. For example in my system it is 8000000 and hence the RAM is split into 32 memory folders from memory0 to memory43. Every 'memoryX' directory will have a file called 'state' which represents the online/offline state of the memory chunk. I can toggle between online/offline if I want to 'switch off' that particular chunk off memory.

So here's what I exactly want to do:

I want to modify this whole directory structure into 4 directories. Why 4? Because, I have 4 X 1GB DIMMS on my motherboard, so I want reduce these 32 memory chunks in to to 4 big chunks so that I can control whichever DIMM I want by toggling it's 'state' online/offline. So Basically I want to change the state of the memory on DIMM level.

That's pretty much my problem description.

My approach: I have read through the sysfs file system and tried to look up the kernel modules which are responsible for organizing the 'memory' directory of sysfs. I want to find the module and edit it as per my requirement and compile that module. It got increasingly difficult to find the specific documentation regarding this topic which lead me to ask this question. All I could find was that there this C programming file '/lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/source/drivers/base/memory.c' which has methods for setting the 'state' of the memory chunks, showing the starting and ending physical address of each memory section and many other methods. But I am not able to figure out where exactly these methods are being called or which module is utilizing this C file to set all the attributes.

Could you please let me know which exact module I need to look for? If you find my approach wrong, could you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How many memory controllers (not channels) does your system have? You know that the data in memory is likely to be stored interleaved, i.e., distributed over all DIMMs?

Comment: I am new to the hardware but as my laptop has core i5, going by the manual I have one integrated dual-channel DDR3 memory controller. And by saying that data is likely to be stored interleaved, you mean to say that it's not possible to divide the memory into chunks? Basically, when I insert my RAM, I want to know which module is responsible for representing it in 8 chunks in sysfs file system so that I can manipulate that to my requirement. Could you please elaborate your comment if I haven't understood it correctly?

Comment: The Core i5 does not have NUMA.

Comment: Oh okay. May be I assumed wrongly that the memory is being split in order to support NUMA for linux in general. I got a bit confused by referring this document (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-memory) which states that when CONFIG_NUMA is enabled /sys/devices/system/node/nodeX/memoryY is a symbolic link that
points to the corresponding /sys/devices/system/memory/memoryY
memory section directory. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I just answer to this part of the question :

> But I am not able to figure out where exactly these methods are being called or which module is utilizing this C file to set all the attributes.

You can use [lxr](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/) to search in the kernel tree.
Here an exemple with [show_mem_state](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=show_mem_state) function.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer but I have been using lxr only to search in the kernel tree but no luck. Not able to narrow down which module is using this file.